# loading spinner in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Class

```
  class Loading extends Component<{},{}> {
      state = {
        sample: [],
        loading: false
      };
      sampleService = new SampleService();

     componentDidMount() {
            this.sampleService
              .getAllSample()
              .then((sample) => {
                this.setState((state) => {
                  return Object.assign(state, { sample: sample });
                });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
      }
```

Component.tsx:

```
render(){
const {loading} = this.state
}
return(
 {loading ? <Spinner/>: <data>
            )}
```

Where should i place the loading variable in componentDidMount to keep it true while data is loading & false when data gets load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `loading` state to `true` before making the request, followed by setting `loading` to `false` after the response is returned (for both successful and failed responses).

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  }):

  this.sampleService
    .getAllSample()
    .then((sample) => {
      this.setState({
        sample, 
        loading: false,
      )}; 
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
       this.setState({
         loading: false,
       )}; 
     });        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
exports class Loading extends Component {
    state = {
        sample: [],
        loading: true
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({sample: sample, loading: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                {this.state.loading ? 
                    <Spinner /> : <Data />
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Check this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it as a `async/await` function  and set your `loading` to `true` before the AJAX call and set it to `false` post receiving the data. You can also set it to `false` during error scenarios

Try something like this

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    try
    {
       const res = await this.sampleService.getAllSample();
       this.setState({sample: res, loading: false);
    }
    catch(err)
    {  
       this.setState({loading:false});
       console.log(err);
    }         
 }
```